# Cadaver/corpse/body for a dead human body

Tags: word-choice

Currently listening to the audio book "Digital Fortress", I came across the word "cadaver" in reference to a dead human body for the first time. Somehow it struck me as a degrading way of referring to it.

So I started wondering what governs the choice of the three words *body*, *cadaver* and *corpse* (and potentially *stiff* and *lich*) for a **dead human body**. I.e. would *cadaver* carry a more formal or medically correct connotation compared to *body* or *corpse*?

Comment: This isn't an answer because it's just my personal intuition: *Cadaver* is medical jargon; I'd be surprised to see it outside of that context. *Corpse* and *body* are both normal usage; *corpse* is slightly more formal (it's what a police officer would say), but more importantly, a corpse is unambiguously *dead*, whereas you can talk about the *body* of someone who is still alive. *Stiff* is dated slang, and *lich* nowadays is only used for a particular type of undead (compare *revenant*) in fantasy fiction.

Comment: I rarely hear "cadaver" used outside a medical setting unless it's being used as an adjective: cadaverous

Comment: Why does it have to be degrading? It's a pretty common word amongst literature and crime shows. According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cadaver) it's a pretty old (1500s) word with latin roots. I've never heard it be used in a degrading manner. It simply is a word that litterally means a dead body.

Comment: I said I *perceived* it as degrading (or probably as choster pointed out *dehumanizing* is the more appropriate term), doesn't mean it has to be. A native speaker of English is clearly more qualified to comment on this, which is why I asked here. Connotations are something you get right from language use. Since I have heard it the first time in this context, I have no experience with the word and lack an idea of the connotations.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: I don't get it. If you had "no experience with the word", where did you get the impression it was "degrading" from?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you do realize that this could be influenced by the respective cognate in my native language, right? ;)

Comment: Technically if it's a cadaver *is it human any more?*

Comment: @0xC0000022L: No, I hadn't thought of that possibility. Is it in fact the case?

Comment: Can we add "carcass" to the list of words asked about? What are the differences among the words cadaver, corpse, body, and carcass?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower 'carcass' is usually used only for animals. If I saw a crow tearing at a carcass in the middle of the road and got closer and realized it was a person, I'd refer to it as 'body' or 'corpse' not 'carcass'. Well, maybe carcass. Hmm...good point..it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Corpse* and *cadaver* are both medical/legal terms for a [dead body](http://thelawdictionary.org/dead-body/). I would not call them degrading per se, but perhaps dehumanizing, and that is not necessarily for ill intent: we use clinical and legal terminology to be precise as well as to avoid emotional or cultural connotations of alternative terms that can be a distraction (e.g. *[pinna](http://visual.merriam-webster.com/human-being/sense-organs/hearing/pinna.php)* as opposed to *ear*, *vertebral column* as opposed to *[backbone](http://thinkexist.com/quotes/with/keyword/backbone/)*).

Although *cadaver* is the [older word](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cadaver), it has come to refer in particular to a dead body used for medical or scientific purposes, for example, [for medical students](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/cadaver) to dissect, while *corpse* is used more generally. I do find *corpse* to be somewhat more evocative than simply *dead body*, as it brings to my mind an embalmed dead body, or the reanimation thereof, but that is likely the fault of too many zombie films.

A more elevated alternative would be *[remains](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/remains)*, and remains which have been elevated  for religious purposes are termed *[relics](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/relics)*.

If on the other hand you did want to disrespect the dead, you could call the dead body a *carcass*, the word for a dead animal body used for food, whether processed by abattoir or buzzard. Etymonline says it is "[not used of humans after c.1750, except contemptuously](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=carcass)."

Comment: Was the body in the story being used for such study? If so, it could be that, far from being degrading, it's most apt word to use.

Comment: @J.R.: The body in the story was at the coroner's office or police station, something like that.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - And which character uttered the phrase? I can see an author having a gritty detective use the word, perhaps as a means of character development.

Comment: @J.R.: "David Becker", a university professor and protagonist. But I think it's just the narrator, not the character that uses the word.

Answer (score 6):

I work with police reports in teaching technical writing skills, and from reading a number of those, the distinction I commonly see (dealing with the same body) is...

> The police officer finds the **dead body**/**body** at the crime
>   scene.
>
> The pathologist autopsies the **cadaver**.
>
> The **corpse** is what gets buried.

In crime reporting, no presumptions are made in advance, so, upon arrival at the scene, a cop will likely not call a body a "dead body" unless there is indisputable proof. That rules out **cadaver** and **corpse**, and sometimes **dead body**, for the purpose of crime scene investigation.

As another answer notes, and the [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cadaver?s=t) of the word commonly attests, **cadaver** implies a human body and is reserved for medical contexts: autopsies, dissections, and the like; and so its use is closely related to a specific context: hospitals, med schools, morgues.

**Corpse**, which also has the meaning of "something no longer useful" or "remains", is the least useful, descriptive, even humane of the three words, and perhaps this is why it's most common in the context of *the thing that gets buried*. Although redundant, **dead body** works in this context too.